# JfileChooser does not close the window after entering a non-existent file

Tags: java, javafx

Sorry for my English. I have to write notepad in javafx. I open new File use FileChooser. And if user type wrong name of file my program have to show communication and extort type correct name file. But when I choose open button  filechooser's window disappear. I want that filechooser window not disappear but user can type correct name file again.

```
public void onActionOpenFile()  {
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    fileChooser.setTitle("Otwórz plik");
    File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(new Stage());
    try {
        if (file.exists()) {
            ReadFile read = new ReadFile(file.getAbsoluteFile().toPath());
            read.readFile();
        } else {

        }
    }catch (NullPointerException e){
        e.getMessage();
    }




}
```

I want that my program work as notepad in windows when I open showOpen dialog and I type wrong name file.

Comment: Post the work you have done till now.

Comment: The problem may be that you have left your else{} code block empty. Try taking some action in the else code block to see if that fix your problem.

Comment: Did not help. I heard about JfileChooser and method approveSelection but I don't know if something like that exist in javafx.

Comment: problem solved.